# Some applications do not remember window state

Tags: gnome, window, 23.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 to 23.04, I noticed that some applications do not remember the window state after they are restarted.

For example, start **Text Editor**, **Thunderbird**, **Thunar**, **Disks**, **Terminal**, or **Geany**. It will start in an un-maximized state. Maximize application's window and close it. Start it again. It will start again in an un-maximized state.

Previous versions of Gnome (XOrg) did not have this problem.

I tested with Ubuntu 23.04 Live ISO and the same problem *is present* there.

I tested with Ubuntu 22.10 Live ISO and the problem *is **not** present* there.

Is there a GNOME setting for applications that do not set their own window state? I guess some applications leave their window state to the desktop manager; is it so?

Comment: Same for me, especially after startup.