# Title bar / full screen in 23.04

Tags: fullscreen, titlebar

Anyone have any idea why since upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04 apps like Kodi and games can no longer go into full screen mode?
The screenshot is Kodi... I get window and top bar, but these weren't shown in 22.10.

Thanks

[image: Kodi]

Comment: Apparently there were quite some last minute upstream changes in the window manager mutter for Gnome 44, which caused difficulties for the Ubuntu developpers. This is probably yet another issue related to that: see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/leading-up-to-23-04-release-things-to-consider/34879 and this question, comments of Jacob Vlijm: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464827/some-applications-are-not-focused-when-clicked-on-their-title-bar?noredirect=1#comment2565506_1464827

Comment: Can this also be  related?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464737/some-applications-do-not-remember-window-state

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. It looks to be a similar issue.

Comment: @FedKad I've just checked and it does the same on here so I assume there is some connection. mutter seems to be the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some applications are not focused when clicked on their Title Bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464827/some-applications-are-not-focused-when-clicked-on-their-title-bar)